# Windows 7 cmd window codepage

Tags: windows-7, command-line

I have weird situation with cmd window codepage on windows 7(32bit).
Since I need codepage 852 this was installed together with windows. Additionally, for DOS programs entry KB16 yu,852 is added in autoexec.nt
All of this works ALMOST good.
To see situation start new cmd window:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\mydir>chcp
Active code page: 852

C:\mydir>command.com
Microsoft(R) Windows DOS
(C)Copyright Microsoft Corp 1990-2001.

C:\MYDIR>chcp
Active code page: 852

C:\MYDIR>exit

C:\mydir>chcp
Active code page: 437
```

By using second shell and exiting from it codepage of my command window changes (by himself) to 437 and that remains until new start of new cmd window.

Why is this happening and how to get upper example to finish with code page 852 since in real situation that way I lose my national specific characters from the screen?
Is here a same command.com in both cases or there is more of it so that can make confusion?